# Must declare the scalar variable "@ID" error, C#, SSIS, in Script task

Tags: c#, sql, ssis, insert, script-task

This is driving me nuts. Probably it is something silly I can't see.

This is my code:

```
cnnDbLocal = new OleDbConnection(localDbStringConnection);
cnnDbLocal.Open();
string select = "INSERT INTO Estimate (EstimateID) VALUES (@IdVal);";
using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(select, cnnDbLocal)) { 
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdVal", 1);
    rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

And I keep getting the error: {"Must declare the scalar variable "@IdVal"."}

I can't believe I cannot figure this out. I tried using the Add() method, but apparently, it is deprecated.

I don't think it is a DB problem, but the code is here anyway:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Estimate](
    [EstimateID] [int] NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [Weight] [float] NULL,
    [FacilityID] [smallint] NULL,
    [JDEFacility] [smallint] NULL,
    [FabricationHours] [float] NULL,
    [CreatedOn] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Thank you for opening my eyes, I am so frustrated this afternoon.

Comment: _Add_ isn't deprecated - see [OleDbParameterCollection.Add Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbparametercollection.add?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0). I don't recommend using [AddWithValue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51682585/10024425) - it will most likely give you unhelpful, and perhaps misleading error messages. OLE DB doesn't support named parameters, see [OLE DB parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51682585/10024425).

Comment: The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69638011/10024425 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/70484316/10024425

Comment: You may try changing `@IdVal` to `!IdVal` to see if it gets rid of the error.

Comment: Any particular reason you are using OleDB anyway? Why not SqlClient and `SqlCommand`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OleDB does not support named parameters. You need to use a `?` and pass the parameters in the correct order. Adjustments made below.

```
Using (OleDbConnection db = new OleDbConnection(localDbStringConnection)) {
    db.Open();
    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand()) {
        cmd.commandText = "INSERT INTO Estimate (EstimateID) VALUES (?);";
        cmd.connection = db;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@IdVal", OleDbType.Integer).value = 1;
        rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This solved my problem and it is working fine now. 

 I will also explore the other users' suggestions since OleDbConnection seems to have many problems.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: It is well worth swapping over to the sqlclient / sql command class instead. Must more user friendly.