Data type mismatched in Critical condition?
i have been creating a vb.net form and when i pass query which takes the data from date picker and textbox to access database and save it in table but insted it gives me error datatype mismatched error
and this is my database

'vb.net code
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports user_regs.AccessDatabase
Imports user_regs.AccessDatabase.Database ' Reference your database module
Public Class Salse_Order
    Private srNoCounter As Integer = 0

    'Private Sub InitializeDataGridView()
    '    DataGridView1.Columns.Add("Sr_no", "Sr. No")
    '    DataGridView1.Columns.Add("So_no", "So_no")
    '    DataGridView1.Columns.Add("item_no", "Item No")
    '    DataGridView1.Columns.Add("description", "Description")
    '    DataGridView1.Columns.Add("quantity", "Quantity")
    '    DataGridView1.Columns.Add("value", "Value")
    '    DataGridView1.Columns.Add("customer_tag_no", "Customer Tag No")
    '    DataGridView1.Columns.Add("cpc_tag_no", "CPC Tag No")
    '    DataGridView1.Columns.Add("production_days", "Production Days")
    '    DataGridView1.Columns.Add("pump_type", "Pump Type")
    '    DataGridView1.Columns.Add("required_delivery_date", "Required Delivery Date")
    '    DataGridView1.Columns.Add("RTS_date", "RTS Date")
    'End Sub
    Private Sub ResetForm()

    End Sub
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
            GroupBox1.Visible = True
            DataGridView1.Visible = True

        Try
            ' Using the Database module to handle the connection and query
            Dim query As String = "INSERT INTO sales_order_header (So_no, SO_date, Customer, Project_name, Delevery_date, order_value) " &
                                  "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"

            ' Parameters for the query with correct data types
            Dim parameters As OleDbParameter() = {
                New OleDbParameter("?", If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text), DBNull.Value, Integer.Parse(TextBox1.Text))),
                New OleDbParameter("?", DateTimePicker2.Value),
                New OleDbParameter("?", TextBox2.Text),
                New OleDbParameter("?", TextBox3.Text),
                New OleDbParameter("?", DateTimePicker1.Value),
                New OleDbParameter("?", If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox4.Text), DBNull.Value, Integer.Parse(TextBox4.Text))) ' Changed to Integer.Parse
            }

            ' Execute the query using the Database module's ExecuteQueryWithParameters function
            Database.ExecuteQueryWithParameters(query, parameters)

            MessageBox.Show("Order Created, add Items")
            TextBox1.ReadOnly = True
            TextBox2.ReadOnly = True
            TextBox3.ReadOnly = True
            TextBox4.ReadOnly = True
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("An error occurred: " & ex.Message)
            ' Reset the form if an error occurs
            ResetForm()
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class

i tryed creating table again and again and tried change the datatype form long int to small int didnt work any help me is there problem with DB or code
after that I found that error is datetimepicker what should be done I don't know

The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70209998/10024425 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/70484316/10024425

I wouldn't create the parameters like that. It's equivalent to using AddWithValue. That has issues even when using actual data but no type can be inferred from DBNull.Value. I suggest that you use the constructor overload that takes a name and an OleDbType and, for text or binary values, a length as well. You can then set the Value property of each parameter. Try that and see if the issue persists. E.g. New OleDbParameter("@SO_date", OleDbType.Date) With {.Value = DateTimePicker2.Value} or New OleDbParameter("@Customer", OleDbType.VarChar, 50) With {.Value = TextBox2.Text}.
